# NestExpressApplication is strict to Content-Type json / raw / text / urlencoded

Tags: express, http, nestjs, content-type, scim

I am working on support SCIM protocol.
The requirements of the protocol specify that the Content-Type header should be sent with application/scim+json.
There is a hard-coded list of supported Content-Type in express application (json / raw / text / urlencoded) so express is removing the body from the request since the default body parser is application/json,

I can't find a way to add different Content-Type format to the supported types.

Is there a way to define which Content-Type can be supported in my application?
I want this to be limited to a specific path prefix, but that's just nice to have.

Thanks!

Comment: express is not removing the body from request, it just doesn't know how to parse it. And `req.body` is for parsed body.

Do you know any expressjs middleware lib that can parse such content?

Comment: @MicaelLeviyou just said what I wrote in different words. I just asked the question, so I have no answer for you

Comment: nop, I'm asking if you know how to parse `application/scim+json` in expressjs, not in nestjs. And you're asking on how to define all the supported content-type in nestjs, which can be easily done using one middleware to check the `content-type` header

Answer (score 0):

you can pass extra types to the `express.json()` middleware options to parse them as JSON.
In your case, the code will be like this

```
app.use(express.json({ type: ["application/json", "application/scim+json"] }));
```